# Office 365 server side email scanner

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I would like to create an application that scans all incoming emails to an entire Office 365 domain and then takes some action based on the contents. Think virus or spam scanner. Are there APIs to do this? It looks like it might be possible using the Graph APIs, but they seem to be more per user focused. I'd like access to emails at a more global level if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can monitor for incoming emails (or any change to any item in any folder) by using the [Outlook Push Notifications REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations).  There's a great code sample [here](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/8755) as well.

Comment: Looks like the push notifications are configured per the current user. How about if I wanted to scan for all users?
...
Target user
The Push Notifications API requests are always performed on behalf of the current user.

Comment: Then you'd have to have access to every user's mailbox and process each one separately. Office 365 doesn't open up access to every mailbox. Only Exchange allows something like that with transport agents: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579261.aspx